# Can my country level domain beat the same .com domain which is own by a different company overseas?

Tags: seo, domains, search-results, ranking, local-seo

I own a country level domain called **`example.lk`** in Sri Lanka.

Also there was a site called **`example.com`** which is own by a reputable company in India. Sadly it is the `.com` version of my domain.

But they are not operating on that `.com` domain, instead they bought it and redirect it to their other site called **`example2.com`**

So their final product which is **`example2.com`** and my site which is **`example.lk`** belongs to same industry. Same business, which is classified ad listing.

So when someone in my country just type **example** word in google we can see their parked domain which is **`example2.com`** in search results. ( because it has huge traffic. but they are not doing any businesses in my country )

So if I start my business with my **`example.lk`** domain, can my domain beat them and appear on the top result within my country?

Can they acquire my domain?

Answer (score 1):

You can beat them.  Will it be automatic?  No.

It will take at least a year and require more than just operating your website on that domain name.  You will need to:

- Offer a quality website that people want to visit.   Your goal should be to be chosen in any head to head comparison.   If people are shown your website and the other, it should be obvious that yours is in every way better.
- Build the reputation of your website.   That will happen naturally over time when you have a quality product.   People who like your site will link to it.   You may need to advertise your website to jump start the process.

Buying the right domain name is not an SEO silver bullet.   A bad name can reflect poorly on your website, but there are many possible good names.   No domain name can get you ranked #1 without lots of hard work on your part.